# Nokia Here JavaScript API disables pinch zoom in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, api, dictionary, here-api

I've just started using the Nokia Here API and it works great, but I've noticed that the maps disable pinch zoom on iOS, on both iPhone and iPad.

Here's an example: http://seemann.com/mapsample/

Works fine across most browsers on a desktop, but pinch zooming is not possible on iOS. (Haven't tested on Android.) This happens even when I turn off the Behavior component.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

A basic pinch zoom functionality **does exist** in the HERE Maps API for Javascript - you just need to include the `Behavior` component as shown.

```
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // initial center and zoom level of the map
    center: [52.51, 13.4],
    zoomLevel: 10,
    components: [
        // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()]
});
```

To take a couple of examples

- [Basic Map Components on developer.here.net](http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/getting-started/basic-map-with-components.html)
- [Headline news story from CNN News](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/01/17/world/meast/algeria-who-is-belmoktar/index.html?hpt=hp_c1)

If you don't include `Behavior` zoom will not work - here is an example

- [Basic Map - no Behavior on developer.here.net](http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/getting-started/basic-map.html)

I've just tested the examples using an iPad and they work fine for me.

According to the [browser support matrix](http://developer.here.net/docs/maps_js/topics/overview.html#browser-support) the API will work on Safari 5+ and iOS 4+

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. My problem isn't zooming in on the map -- that works just fine, thanks to the behavior component you point out -- but pinch-zoom is disabled for the *rest* of the page.