# Nokia here map and mobile pinch zoom

Tags: html, mobile, here-api

I used Nokia here map (version 2.5.4) within my web application, but if I open my web site on mobile device (Tested on Android 4.x Nexus 7 ,IOS7 IPhone5c ) it is unable pinch-to-zoom. 
I also found a similar issue:
[Nokia Here JavaScript API disables pinch zoom in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304282/nokia-here-javascript-api-disables-pinch-zoom-in-ios)

I also try downgrade here map API version to 2.2.3, pinch-to-zoom is working but I cannot use the built-in marker function in 2.2.3 version.

Any solution/suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! 
First we detect client , if client device is mobile/tablet
Than load 2.2.1 here map , otherwise load newly version

In my case , i also need use custom icon marker with overlay text .

In newly version , i can use https://github.com/heremaps/examples/tree/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/text-on-icon-marker to meet the requirement.

Unfortunately , in 2.2.1 above solution is not working, but we can referring to http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/playground/examples/maps/map_objects/customsvgmarker.html using SVG image instead of bitmap .

But this solution only working on Android 4.x . 
IOS is not working

Answer (score 1):

Please use the newest Here Maps API for JavaScript 3.0, you can find more information on [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html), this Version is optimized for mobile usage.

An extensive set of examples for the API can be found on the [API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer).
There is also a [migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions) available to help your upgrade from 2.x to 3.x